# Storing All the data coming from API call based on some parameters in a List

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

[image]I Have a list containing some ids, I have to call an api with each of ids in the list and store all the data that comes from the api in a list,I am mapping through the list and calling the api with each id and then pushing the data into an array,but when I finally check the array it gives inconsistent result,sometimes it returns all the data,some time some of the data or sometimes the list is empty,here is my react code

```
let deviceidlist=['eb77fa554fbdbed47dkubk','ebbaa8d217947ff4d1fk3w','ebe55d36879c7fd71emtf0','eb645acaa1efb456877nss','ebc32ad422bc5dc3eecapa','ebf5bb435e688e96e8mt5z','45102754e09806133d2d','eb7c72ba426f92b9a1pb81','eb84a574ecfa372e6ccapr','eb458f73adadf67170uxdv']
  
  let devicelist=[]
  useEffect(()=>{
   const datafetch=async()=>{
   deviceidlist.map((item)=>{fetch(`http://localhost:8000/api/switch/${item}`).then(data=>data.json()).then(data=>devicelist.push(data))})
   }

datafetch()
   

  
}
,[])
  
console.log(devicelist)
```

I am trying to store all the data that I get back from api to store in a list but getting an empty array

Comment: Did you try to put devicelist in the local state: const [devicelist, setDevicelist] = useState([]) and then add data to that state?

Comment: I have but in that case the state gets updated for each id,but i need all the data of all the ids and store them together in a list so I can use them later on

Answer (score 1):

Fetching data from API is an asynchronous task, consoling right after the API call may not give the expected result. That's the reason you are getting multiple results
try adding the deviceList to a state so it will be

```
const[deviceList, setDeviceList] = useState([]);
  useEffect(()=>{
   const datafetch=async()=>{
   deviceidlist.map((item)=>{fetch(`http://localhost:8000/api/switch/${item}`).then(data=>data.json()).then(data=>{
setDeviceList([...deviceList, data]);
})})
   }
datafetch()
}
,[])
```

Try consoling the deviceList (state update will re-render the component and will console the updated data)

Comment: It is working but since the state is getting updated every time, at the last call the state is updated to the data of the last id,but I need all those 10 data stored together in a list

Comment: Actually, the state is updating along with the previous state value
setDeviceList([...deviceList, data]);

Comment: I have attached a screenshot of the result

Comment: Can you please share your code in codesandbox?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/still-fast-554lx8?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

Try to fetch the data asynchronously and then set it to the state instead of pushing it into the array. Something like this :

```
import React from 'react';
import { useEffect } from 'react';

export default function App() {

  let deviceidlist = [
    'eb77fa554fbdbed47dkubk',
    'ebbaa8d217947ff4d1fk3w',
    'ebe55d36879c7fd71emtf0',
    'eb645acaa1efb456877nss',
    'ebc32ad422bc5dc3eecapa',
    'ebf5bb435e688e96e8mt5z',
    '45102754e09806133d2d',
    'eb7c72ba426f92b9a1pb81',
    'eb84a574ecfa372e6ccapr',
    'eb458f73adadf67170uxdv',
  ];

  const deviceList = [];


  useEffect( async() => {
    try {
      let response = await deviceidlist.map((item) => { fetch(`http://localhost:8000/api/switch/${item}`) })
      if (response.ok) {
        let data = await response.json()
        deviceList.push(data)
      } else {
        console.log("failed")
      }
    } catch(error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  })

  return (
   <div></div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I need to store all the data I get back from the api in a list,so I can use them later for a different purpose

Comment: If you want to store them in a list, change `const [deviceList, setdeviceList] = useState([]);` into `const deviceList = []`, and then instead of setting the state like this here `setdeviceList(data)` push the data like the old way you were doing it. but i am not sure.

Comment: modified into array